# compute pointwise distance by group in R with sf dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf

I have 2 dataframes. I want to compute the distance between all POINT geometries if the first frame with respect to a certain POINT in the second dataframe. The main feature of this problem is that I have a *grouping* variable in the first dataframe, and I would like to select the corresponding point to measure the distance to (in the second dataframe) according to this grouping indicator. I tried with `group_by`:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

d = data.frame(x = 1:10,y = 1:10, g = rep(c("a","b"),each=5))
d_sf = st_as_sf(d,coords = c("x","y") )
d_sf

Simple feature collection with 10 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
   g      geometry
1  a   POINT (1 1)
2  a   POINT (2 2)
3  a   POINT (3 3)
4  a   POINT (4 4)
5  a   POINT (5 5)
6  b   POINT (6 6)
7  b   POINT (7 7)
8  b   POINT (8 8)
9  b   POINT (9 9)
10 b POINT (10 10)

centers = d %>% group_by(g) %>% summarise(x = mean(x), y = mean(y))
centers
centers_sf = st_as_sf(centers, coords = c("x","y"))
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 3 ymin: 3 xmax: 8 ymax: 8
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  g     geometry
  <fct>  <POINT>
1 a        (3 3)
2 b        (8 8)

d_sf %>% group_by(g) %>% st_distance(centers_sf,by_element = TRUE)
 [1] 2.828427 8.485281 0.000000 5.656854 2.828427 2.828427 5.656854 0.000000 8.485281 2.828427

# but really I want this:
> st_distance(d_sf[1,],centers_sf[1,])
         [,1]
[1,] 2.828427
> st_distance(d_sf[2,],centers_sf[1,])
         [,1]
[1,] 1.414214
> st_distance(d_sf[3,],centers_sf[1,])
     [,1]
[1,]    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)

d_sf %>%
  mutate(dst = map2_dbl(g, geometry,
    ~ st_distance(.y, centers_sf %>% filter(g == .x) %>% pull(geometry))
  ))
```

Output:

```
   g      dst      geometry
1  a 2.828427   POINT (1 1)
2  a 1.414214   POINT (2 2)
3  a 0.000000   POINT (3 3)
4  a 1.414214   POINT (4 4)
5  a 2.828427   POINT (5 5)
6  b 2.828427   POINT (6 6)
7  b 1.414214   POINT (7 7)
8  b 0.000000   POINT (8 8)
9  b 1.414214   POINT (9 9)
10 b 2.828427 POINT (10 10)
```

Comment: wow, that is exactly what im looking for! but there are a couple of things that are new to me. in `map2_dbl(g, geometry,
    ~ st_distance(.y, centers_sf %>% filter(g == .x) %>% pull(geometry)`, i am trying to understand how this relates to what i see [here](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html): `.x` is piped in, `.y` is `g` (?) and `geometry` is a function? why is there another formula there after? thanks for all!

Comment: With `map2` you are looping through all values of `g` and `geometry` columns of `d_sf` dataframe. `.x` is related to `g` and `.y` to `geometry`. With `centers_sf %>% filter(g == .x) %>% pull(geometry)` I am just pulling `geometry` value from `centers_sf` with corresponding `g` value.

Comment: hmm, unfortunately this solution doesn't work in my real world application. it complains about x and y not having the same crs, even though `st_crs(d_sf) == st_crs(centers_sf)` is `TRUE`. something breaks inside that map2 call i think.

Comment: @FlorianOswald If you will update the question (put samples of datasets that you have problem with) maybe I will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly modified answer that works when crs is defined:

```
d_sf$dst <- map_dbl(1:nrow(d_sf), function(x){
  x <- d_sf[x,]
  y <- centers_sf[centers_sf$g == x$g,]
  st_distance(x, y)
})
```

Comment: thanks! this does work as well. however it's quite a slow loop. my current solution is to loop over all unique values of `g`, and make use of the vectorized version of `st_distance`. It's not pretty, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

d_sf2 <- d_sf %>% group_by(g) %>% nest(.key="d")
centers_sf2 <- centers_sf %>% group_by(g) %>% nest(.key="centers")

d_sf2 %>% left_join(centers_sf2) %>% 
  mutate(dst= map2(d, centers, st_distance)) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(dst=dst[,1]) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
   g     geometry geometry1   dst
   <chr>  <POINT>   <POINT> <dbl>
 1 a        (1 1)     (3 3)  2.83
 2 a        (2 2)     (3 3)  1.41
 3 a        (3 3)     (3 3)  0   
 4 a        (4 4)     (3 3)  1.41
 5 a        (5 5)     (3 3)  2.83
 6 b        (6 6)     (8 8)  2.83
 7 b        (7 7)     (8 8)  1.41
 8 b        (8 8)     (8 8)  0   
 9 b        (9 9)     (8 8)  1.41
10 b      (10 10)     (8 8)  2.83
```

The trick to avoid the crs error here is to feed sf's or sfc's from both data to st_distance(). The solution by Paweł Chabros fed sfg from d_sf and sfc from centers_sf. sfg does not contain CRS information.